# Ansible: merge dictionaries appending values

Tags: data-structures, ansible

How can I get a dictionary with values from input separated with a comma? There can be a different number and order of input parameters. What I've tried just gives the error below

```
- set_fact:
    input:
      - port: 1234
        protocol: TCP
        messages: 888-999
        file: s3://somepath/file.xsl
      - protocol: TLS
        port: 5678
        path: s3://somepath/mycertificate.crt
        messages: 345, 467, 888
        file: s3://somepath/file2.xsl

- set_fact:
    final_dict:
      finalFile: item | map(attribute='file')| join(',')
      finalFilter: item | map(attribute='messages')| join(',')
      finalPath: item | map(attribute='path')| join(',')
      finalProtocol: item | map(attribute='protocol')| join(',')
      finalPort: item | map(attribute='port')| join(',')
  loop: "{{ input }}"
```

The error message is as follows:

```
>"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'file'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have three issues here:

1. if you intend to use `map`, then you need to do it on a list, so, you should have expressions like

   ```yaml
   var: input | map(attribute='file')
   ```

   And not act on the `item` of a `loop`.
2. you are missing the `{{ ... }}` expression delimiters in your `final_dict`, e.g.:

   ```yaml
   finalFile: "{{ input | map(attribute='file') | join(',') }}"
   ```

   and not

   ```yaml
   finalFile: input | map(attribute='file') | join(',')
   ```
3. Because you do have some undefined keys in your list of dictionaries `input`, you want to use the `default` value of `map`:

   ```yaml
   finalPath: "{{ input | map(attribute='path', default='') | join(',') }}"
   ```

- *(optionally) if you are going to use `input` only in that context, make it a variable block. [You can define it at the level of the task, play, inventory, ...](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#where-to-set-variables)*

Given these three remarks, those two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    final_dict:
      finalFile: "{{ input | map(attribute='file') | join(',') }}"
      finalFilter: "{{ input | map(attribute='messages') | join(',') }}"
      finalPath: "{{ input | map(attribute='path', default='') | join(',') }}"
      finalProtocol: "{{ input | map(attribute='protocol') | join(',') }}"
      finalPort: "{{ input | map(attribute='port') | join(',') }}"
  vars:
    input:
      - port: 1234
        protocol: TCP
        messages: 888-999
        file: s3://somepath/file.xsl
      - protocol: TLS
        port: 5678
        path: s3://somepath/mycertificate.crt
        messages: 345, 467, 888
        file: s3://somepath/file2.xsl

- debug:
    var: final_dict
```

Would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  final_dict:
    finalFile: s3://somepath/file.xsl,s3://somepath/file2.xsl
    finalFilter: 888-999,345, 467, 888
    finalPath: ',s3://somepath/mycertificate.crt'
    finalPort: 1234,5678
    finalProtocol: TCP,TLS
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How can I omit an undefined value with map? Because default(omit) doesn't work and default='' doesn't work well for me

Comment: I went for lists and select('defined') in the end: finalPath: "{{ input | map(attribute='path') | select('defined') | list }}"